# Why do we have zero as the value of the derivative at optimum

Tags: statistics, derivatives, maximum-likelihood

$\newcommand{\dd}{\partial}$When searching for the mean and variance of a Gaussian distribution, we are trying to minimise this equation:
$$
\hat{\mu}, \hat{\sigma} = \arg\min_{\mu,\sigma} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left\{\frac{(x_{i} - \mu)^{2}}{2\sigma^{2}} + \ln\sigma\right\}.
$$

However, why do we need to minimise these derivatives at optimum?

How do we know that the point which has the derivative $0$ is a global minimum and not a global maximum?

- At optimum,
  $$
  \frac{\dd J}{\dd \mu} = 0 \to \hat{\mu},\qquad\qquad
  \frac{\dd J(\hat{\mu}, \sigma)}{\dd\sigma} = 0 \to \hat{\sigma}.
  $$

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing by doing those computations is computing the maximum likelihood estimators for $\mu$ and $\sigma$. The likelihood is maximised precisely when the first expression you listed is minimised (this is not very hard to check). To minimise, take the derivative and set equal to zero.

Comment: How do we know the point with derivative 0 is a global minimum and not a global maximum?

Comment: Note that the expression is unbounded in $\mu$.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that.